# How to add a menu to the main (top) menu in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to add the Team menu (which currently appears as a context menu in the package explorer) with all its corresponding actions, to the main menu in Eclipse. How can I do that?
I think somebody helped me do it once, but I don't remember the steps.

Comment: you mean `Team` tab in eclipse ?

Comment: @Ros5292 I don't know what you mean by Team "tab"

Comment: In _Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective..._ tab _Action Set Availability_ check _Git_. Is this what you've been looking for?

Comment: @howlger no, I'm looking for Team. I don't even have Git installed in Eclipse. There's a Team action set, but it doesn't provide a Team menu. I'm currently looking into writing a plugin to add that. I thought it wasn't necessary to go that far...

Comment: @aditsu _Team_ is a generic context submenu. It depends on which menu entries of which plug-ins you want to see when (on which resources should the actions in the menu be executed?). It's not Git, but then what is it?

Comment: @howlger yes, I'm aware that Team contains different things for different projects. I would like the menu to apply to the current project, just like when going to Project -> Properties from the main menu. Or alternatively, current selection in the package explorer could be fine too. As for what I have in Team if not Git, it's Mercurial or SVN (depending on the project), but if I were to install and use Git, that should work too.

Comment: @aditsu The _Team_ context menu of a project and of a file contain different actions. Therefore it would make more sense to add project actions to the _Project_ main menu IMHO. On which resource an action should be executed must be implemented for menus (regardless of where a menu item is displayed). Also when a menu item should be disabled or should be hidden can be different from the context menu. This has to be defined and implemented by each team provider for each menu item.

Comment: @howlger well, let me say it this way: I'd like to have a Team menu that works EXACTLY the same way as the Team submenu when right-clicking on either 1) the current project or 2) the current selection in the package explorer. It's already implemented on right-click, I'd just like to have it in the main menu. Besides, I've already seen it done once, although that was some 12 years ago.

Comment: @aditsu Eclipse provides the infrastructure to add menu entries. The menu entries must be implemented and added by each team provider. This was no different 12 years ago. For example, in EGit the optional main menu is called _Git_ instead of _Team_ and entries are deactivated and not hidden. I guess this is to avoid confusion with actions of the same name (e. g. _commit_ has a different meaning in Git than in SVN). In Eclipse there is no general setting to show a _Team_ menu, but one or more plug-ins might provide via so-called action sets _Team_ menu entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188209/discussion-between-aditsu-and-howlger).